# Is there any difference between p.class-name and p[class=class-name]?

Tags: css-selectors

Like in title I have a question about css selectors.  Is there any difference between p.class-name and p[class=class-name]? Which is more preferable to use?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `p[class=class-name]` works only if the class attribute is exactly `"class-name"`. Like

```
<p class="class-name">
```

But the class attribute can contain more than one class. For example,

```
<p class="class-name other-class-name">
```

has two classes, `class-name` and `other-class-name` and can be matched by `p.class-name`, but not by `p[class=class-name]`.

So the answer to what is more preferable depends on your use case.